# Strange transactional id errors when using the kafka sink

Tags: apache-flink

I had a Flink 1.15.1 job configured with

```
execution.checkpointing.mode='EXACTLY_ONCE'
```

that was failing with the following error

```
Sink: Committer (2/2)#732 (36640a337c6ccdc733d176b18adab979) switched from INITIALIZING to FAILED with failure cause: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to commit KafkaCommittable{producerId=4521984, epoch=0, transactionalId=}
...
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Invalid value  for configuration transactional.id: String must be non-empty
```

that happened after the first checkpoint was triggered. The strange thing about it is that the `KafkaSinkBuilder` was used without calling `setDeliverGuarantee`, and hence the default delivery guarantee was expected to be used, which is `NONE` [1](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/f494be6956e850d4d1c9fd50b79e5a8dd5b53e47/flink-connectors/flink-connector-kafka/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/connector/kafka/sink/KafkaSinkBuilder.java#L66).

Is that even possible to start with? Shouldn't kafka transactions be involved only when one follows this recipe in [2](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/f494be6956e850d4d1c9fd50b79e5a8dd5b53e47/flink-connectors/flink-connector-kafka/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/connector/kafka/sink/KafkaSinkBuilder.java#L51)?

```
 * <p>One can also configure different {@link DeliveryGuarantee} by using {@link
 * #setDeliverGuarantee(DeliveryGuarantee)} but keep in mind when using {@link
 * DeliveryGuarantee#EXACTLY_ONCE} one must set the transactionalIdPrefix {@link
 * #setTransactionalIdPrefix(String)}.
```

So, in my case, without calling `setDeliverGuarantee` (nor `setTransactionalIdPrefix`), I cannot understand why I was seeing these errors. To avoid the problem, I temporarily relaxed the checkpointing settings to

```
execution.checkpointing.mode='AT_LEAST_ONCE'
```

but I'd like to understand what was happening.

Answer (score 1):

Like the JavaDoc mentions, if you enable exactly-once, you must set a transactionalIdPrefix. A complete recipe on how-to configure exactly-once with Apache Kafka can be found in this recipe: https://www.docs.immerok.cloud/docs/cookbook/exactly-once-with-apache-kafka-and-apache-flink/

Disclaimer: I work for Immerok

Comment: To be clear, my setup was using `execution.checkpointing.mode='EXACTLY_ONCE' `and `NONE` delivery guarantee for the kafka sink. Can the above transactional id error actually happen under these circumstances? I've indeed seen the error, but in theory, that should not happen (no kafka transactions should be used for the `NONE` delivery guarantee nor for `AT_LEAST_ONCE`).

Comment: Yes, because setting the checkpointing mode to EXACTLY_ONCE will automatically start using transactional IDs. It takes priority over the default delivery guarantee.

Comment: So, I understand that I can make the kafka sink automatically adapt to the global (checkpointing.mode) guarantee by calling `setTransactionalIdPrefix("XYZ")` without explicitly calling `setDeliveryGuarantee`. This way, if `EXACTLY_ONCE` is used for the checkpoints, the kafka sink will have a properly defined transactional id. And if I lower the guarantee for the checkpoints, then it won't be used. Does it make sense or should I explicitly and consistently set both guarantees?